# A word which means "sudden drop"

Tags: word-request

Can someone please tell me a word which means "sudden drop"? I want to use that word to say that there is a sudden drop in velocity.

Comment: Sudden as in occurring over a short time? Or sudden as in without warning? Or sudden as in a very large relative to typical changes?

Comment: Isn't it good enough to just say "a drop in velocity?" Otherwise you could say "sudden deceleration." It would be good to know more circumstances, though.

Comment: *rapid deceleration* is about as good as I can suggest

Comment: @ puppetsock reinstate Monica and @ Jan , I want to say that there is a sudden drop in the velocity of the fluid which passes around an aerofoil.